# How do we control the automatic dividers in SwiftUI forms?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I'm curious, is there a way we can control (or make sense of) the automatic dividers that swiftui puts between items?

Here's some code showing strange behaviour (on iOS simulator):

```swift
struct FormSeparator: View {
    @State private var passwd = ""
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                TextField("password", text:$passwd)
                Text("8 chars min")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            TextField("confirm", text:$passwd)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: example of strange divider]

This seems to have something to do with the `Text` that I'm stacking on top of the password field. If I change it the Text to `Image(systemName: "lock")` then everything works as you'd expect:

[image: example of normal divider]

Mind you, I don't even understand why it doesn't extend all the way across the form in that case. Presumably this is deliberate, has anyone seen anything official about this situation? Do we know how to control this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 16, List/Form row separator insets automatically and aligns with the text. In iOS 16, we got two new alignments, [`listRowSeparatorLeading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/horizontalalignment/listrowseparatorleading) and [`listRowSeparatorTrailing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/horizontalalignment/listrowseparatortrailing), to work with [`alignmentGuide(_:computeValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alignmentguide(_:computevalue:)-6y3u2).

```
ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
    TextField("password", text:$passwd)
    Text("8 chars min")
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
}
.alignmentGuide(.listRowSeparatorLeading) { viewDimensions in
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That does the trick! I would simplify your solution slightly by using `{ _ in 0 }` instead of the full closure syntax.

Comment: Actually, better yet, would probably be `{ $0[.leading] }`

Comment: But I can't find anything that will make it go all the way to the left. Right now it just matches the left side of the TextField. I'd like it to go all the way to the edge of the section border. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: @CuriousJorge I have tried to make the separator start from the left. Not found any default but you can return `-20` instead of `0` in the same closure as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that -20 works for me, thanks. But of course, this is not an ideal solution, since there's little guarantee it will be correct in other situations. Hopefully Apple gives us a better way to solve this.

Comment: @CuriousJorge Yes, it's not an ideal solution just a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lazy workaround if you want to support iOS 15. You can add a `Text("")` element at the start of the HStack.

The Form draws the dividers in alignment with the first Text element. That's why the divider starts halfway over when the "8 chars min" text is shown, but not when the lock image is shown instead. (why you be like this siwftui?)

This workaround is unacceptable if your rows will be above/below other textfields though, as it will appear with slightly more leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding .listRowSeparator(.visible)